# Why does applying 'com.android.library' plugin break references?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a build.gradle file for my library that contains `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

In my MainActivity.kt file I have:

```
package com.foo.networkdiagnostics

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var text: AppCompatEditText
    lateinit var result: AppCompatTextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        text = findViewById(R.id.sample_text)
        result = findViewById(R.id.result)
```

When I have that `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in my library's build.gradle file, I start seeing errors like this in my MainActivity.kt:

```
Unresolved reference: layout :15
Unresolved reference: id :17
Unresolved reference: id :18
Unresolved reference: id :20
```

If I comment out that `apply plugin` line, the "Unresolved reference" errors go away. What is causing this to happen?

This is Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3

EDIT: Here is the :app build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foo.networkdiagnostics"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//    implementation project(':library')
}
```

And the :library build.gradle only has `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Comment: How about this https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#PrivateResources

Comment: In my case removing import android.R solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please note starting from android 4.1 you don't have to use "apply" for plugins you can use "id" instead.

e.g:

```
before:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

after:
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the info but this would be better as a comment to my original question rather than an answer, since it doesn't directly address the problem.